# Error Traverse List of LinkedList in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, singly-linked-list, dereference

I written the following code but When I am trying to compile the code, Compiler shows the following error. Where is my fault?

Compiler Error :

> main.c:32:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Information’
>          printf("Information : %d\n", ptr->_number);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Informaion{
    int _number;
    struct Informaion *next;
} Information;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    Information *temp;
    Information *head;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
    temp->_number = 20;
    head = temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
    temp->_number = 21;
    head->next = temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
    temp->_number = 22;
    head->next->next = temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
    temp->_number = 23;
    head->next->next->next = NULL;

    struct Information *ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
      printf("Information : %d\n", ptr->_number);
      ptr = ptr->next;
   }

    free(head);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many typographics errors within your struct. I don't know what you are trying to do since you don't say it, but if you want to print an adress, use `%p` instead of `%d`

Comment: I want to show data that I set for structure. I fix it.

Comment: @MikhailRazborov if your problem is fixed, you could accept one answer.

Comment: When calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the alternate signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: there is a lot of variation in how the word: Information (or is it Informaion) is spelled, so the code does not compile.  Note: leading Underscores are 'reserved' for the compiler.  Suggest renaming `_number` to `number`

Comment: for every call to `malloc()` there must be a call to `free()` using the same pointers returned from `malloc()`.  As it is,  the code has lots of memory leaks  Suggest replacing `free(head); free(temp);` with: `while( head) { ptr = head->next; free( head ); head = ptr; }`

Comment: the line: `head->next->next->next = NULL;` is not correct   the results of the last call to `malloc()` should be stored not NULL.  then set the final `next` field with: `head->next->next->next->next = NULL;`.  BTW:  this stringing the `->next` fields together is not a good idea,  It will not expand to when there are many linked instances of `struct Informaion`.  Suggest using a `for()` loop, keeping track of the prior linked entry and using that to link  the next entry. Also it is usually best to initialize all fields of a new entry before linking it

Answer (score 3):

The name of your type is `struct Informaion`. In the line you are using

```
struct Information *ptr = head;
```

To solve the problem you can fix the typo or you can use it by the typedef directly.

```
Information *ptr = head;
```

As a general practice you should not use variables or any identifiers starting with underscore. These are reserved for the compiler. Suggest you change `_number` to something else.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the structure definition

```
typedef struct Informaion{
                     ^^^  
    int _number;
    struct Informaion *next;
} Information;
```

So either use type specifier `struct Informaion` or `Information` everywhere below in declarations.

This code snippet

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
temp->_number = 23;
head->next->next->next = NULL;
```

does not make sense. The allocated object the address of which stored in the pointer temp is not added to the list.

It would be correctly to write

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(Information));
temp->_number = 23;
head->next->next->next = temp;
head->next->next->next->next = NULL;
```

To free the allocated nodes you should write

```
for ( Information *ptr = head; head != NULL; ptr = head) {
  head = head->next;
  free( ptr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line :

```
struct Information *ptr = head;
```

to :

```
struct Informaion *ptr = head;  //no t
```

or :

```
Information *ptr = head;
```

and the error will disappear. The type you can defined can be named either using `struct Informaion` or `Information`, as you have `typedef`ed it.

---

***Note*** that using variables starting with underscore (such as your `_number` variable) is not encouraged, as these names are used by the compiler.